# Creating a list of triangle-square numbers up to n_

Tags: list-manipulation

I have to, for a class, create a function that gives you the [triangular-square numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number) up to n.

That said, here's the code I have:

```
triquadEul = Function[n, Module[{triquadform, w, l, i, r},
(*Euler's formula for triangular-square numbers (1778) \
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number)*)
triquadform[k_] := (((3 + 2 Sqrt[2])^k - (3 - 2 Sqrt[2])^k)/(4 Sqrt[2]))^2;
i = 1;
r = {};
l = 1;
While[l <= n,
 l = triquadform[i];
 Append[r, l];
 i = i + 1;
 ];
r]];
```

This, however, only produces an empty list, whatever n I use. I've successfully used this formula to calculate triangular-square numbers, but when I tried to limit the calculations to only calculate for triangular-square numbers under *n*, so as to augment efficiency, I started only getting an empty list and I can't for the life of my find out why.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks very much.

Comment: Look at the [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A001110) for square triangular numbers, and look under the **Mathematica** tab for formulas. One I particularly like (from T. D. Noe, Mar 25 2011) is `LinearRecurrence[{35, -35, 1}, {1, 36, 1225}, 20]` (I shifted the initial conditions so that it starts at 1 instead of 0 for first sequence term)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[n_] := Module[{s2 = 2 Sqrt[2], p, k},
                p = (((3 + s2)^# - (3 - s2)^#)/2/ s2)^2 &; 
                p@Range[k /. NSolve[p@k == n && n > 0, k, Reals]] // Simplify //Last]

f[8787534]
(* {1, 36, 1225, 41616, 1413721} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[n_: Integer] := Module[{a = {}},
  k = 1;
  While[(t = (((3 + 2 Sqrt[2])^k - (3 - 2 Sqrt[2])^k)/(
        4 Sqrt[2]))^2) <= n, AppendTo[a, t]; k++];
  IntegerPart@N@a
  ]

f[8787534]

{1, 36, 1225, 41616, 1413720}
```

Comment: I had something to this effect set up recently my problem is that I my assignment requires me to write a program that will return all the triangular-square numbers smaller than n, not all the trisquare numbers up to the nth trisquare number. I could just cut the end-list, but that'll be a loss in performance (performing unnecessary calculations on the list that will later be cut) and I'll be rated in efficiency. Actually, nevermind. Your way is ultra efficient and timing probably won't be a problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
f[n_] := Denominator[Convergents[Sqrt[8], n][[2 ;; n ;; 2]]]^2
```

For example: `f[20]`:

{1, 36, 1225, 41616, 1413721, 48024900, 1631432881, 55420693056, 
1882672131025, 63955431761796}

Answer (score 0):

**Using `PolygonalNumber`:**

```
triSq[n_Integer /; n > 0] := Module[{
   lim = Reduce[PolygonalNumber[k] < n, k] // N // Last // Ceiling},
  Echo[lim];
  PolygonalNumber /@ Range[lim] // Select[IntegerQ[Sqrt[#]] &]
  ]

triSq[1000]
```

> {1, 36}

```
triSq[8787534]
```

> {1, 36, 1225, 41616, 1413721}

---

*Historical note*

```
WolframLanguageData["PolygonalNumber"
 , {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}]
```

{10.4, DateObject[{2016, 3, 2}, "Day", "Gregorian", 5.]}